# Solving for x in a trig function

Tags: trigonometry

Assuming $R_E$, $h$ and $Φ$ are constants, is there a way to solve for ε in terms of the constants? Found the following equation [in a paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/101448) to calculate angle of elevation.

cos
  ⁡
  (
  ε+Φ
  )/
  cos
  ⁡
  (
  ε
  )
  =
  $\frac{R_E}{(R_E+h)}$

Thanks!

Comment: Start by applying angle sum identity for cosine in numerator of fraction on left hand side.

Comment: If you use the angle sum identity and let $x = \cos\epsilon$, $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \sin\epsilon$ and simplify, you will get a quadratic in $x$.

Comment: If you write $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+1/e^{ix}}{2}$ you see right away how your equation is a rational/polynomial equation in $e^{i\epsilon}$, quadratic actually.

Comment: Your MathMl looks  professional, but there is also [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for this website

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity $\cos(\epsilon+\Phi) = \cos(\epsilon)\cos(\Phi) - \sin(\epsilon)\sin(\phi)$, $\frac{\sin(\epsilon)}{\cos(\epsilon)} = \tan(\epsilon)$, and some algebra, you get:

$$\epsilon = \arctan\left(\frac{-R_E + (R_E + h)\cos(\Phi)}{(R_E + h)\sin(\Phi)}\right)$$

Comment: Looks great. Thank you!